# Soft body ball just teleports down

Tags: soft-body

soft body ball just "teleports" down.

[image: frame 0]

[image: frame 2]

[Download Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xbikSykrg5mjb5W1ANvdEqk2W9E6rUjY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It runs fine on my PC, I think your Cache is messed up. Try "Free all bakes" then rerun the simulation (from frame 1).

Comment: ok i will try it